# How to use sed to replace multiple chars in a string?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace some chars of a string with sed.

I tried the following two approaches, but I need to know if there is a more elegant form to get the same result, without using the pipes or the `-e` option:

```
sed 's#a#A#g' test.txt | sed 's#l#23#g' > test2.txt
sed -e 's#a#A#g' -e 's#l#23#g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of multiple `-e` options, you can separate commands with `;` in a single argument.

```
sed 's/a/A/g; s/1/23/g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

If you're looking for a way to do multiple substitutions in a single command, I don't think there's a way. If they were all single-character replacements you could use a command like `y/abc/123`, which would replace `a` with `1`, `b` with `2`, and `c` with `3`. But there's no multi-character version of this.

Comment: Thanks for the support Barmar, this is a finest way to get the same result.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer of Barmar, you might want to use regexp character classes to perform several chars to one specific character substitution.

Here's an example to clarify things, try to run it with and without `sed` to feel the effect

`echo -e 'abc\ndef\nghi\nklm' | sed 's/[adgk]/1/g; s/[behl]/2/g; s/[cfim]/3/g'`

P.S. never run example code from strangers outside of safe sandbox

Comment: + for your P.S. ... I would add: never run example code without understanding what you are doing :D

Answer (score 2):

When you have a lot strings for the replacement, you can collect them in a variable.

```
seds="s/a/A/;"
seds+="s/1/23/;"
echo "That was 1 big party" |
   sed ${seds}
```